# Django Dev/Prod Deployment using Mercurial

Tags: python, django, mercurial, fabric

I've a puzzle of a development and production Django setup that I can't figure out a good way to deploy in a simple way. Here's the setup:

- `/srv/www/projectprod` contains my production code, served at www.domain.com
- `/srv/www/projectbeta` contains my development code, served at www.dev.domain.com
- Prod and Dev are also split into two different virtualenvs, to isolate their various Python packages, just in case.

What I want to do here is to make a bunch of changes in dev, then push to my Mercurial server, and then re-pull those changes in production when stable. But there are a few things making this complicated:

- wsgi.py contains the `activate_this.py` call for the virtualenv, but the path is scoped to either prod or dev, so that needs to be edited before deployment.
- manage.py has a shebang at the top to define the correct python path for the virtualenv. (This is currently `#!/srv/ve/.virtualenvs/project-1.2/bin/python` so I'm wondering if I can just remove this to simplify things)
- settings.py contains paths to the templates, staticfiles, media root, etc. which are all stored under `/srv/www/project[prod|dev]/*`

I've looked into Fabric, but I don't see anything in it that would re-write these files for me prior to doing the mercurial push/pull.

Does anyone have any tips for simplifying this, or a way to automate this deployment?

Comment: Add info about how exactly you make deployments.

Answer (score 0):

- Two branches for different environment (with env-specific changes in each, thus - additional merge before deploy)

or

- MQ extension, "clean" code in changesets, MQ-patch for every environment on top of single branch (and accuracy with apply|unapply of patches)